# How can I url-encode a translated block of text with variables?

Tags: django, localization, django-templates

I am trying to `urlencode` a translated block of text that contains variables in a Django (1.6.1) template. I need to do this because of a `mailto` link that contains a translated subject:

```
<a href="mailto:me@example.com?subject=_('Hello {{ username }}')|urlencode">Send email</a>
```

Except this code produces the following output:

```
<a href="mailto:me@example.com?subject=Hello%20%7D%7Dusername%7D%7D%20">Send email</a>
```

So, obviously, the `username` variable was not evaluated by the `_()` operator. If I'm not mistaken, the only translation tag that can evaluate variables is `blocktrans`.

So, what would be great would be to store the subject translation in a dedicated variable. Something like:

```
{% blocktrans as subject %}Hello {{ username }}{% endblocktrans %}
<a href="mailto:me@example.com?subject={{ subject|urlencode }}">Send email</a>
```

Except that "as" is not a valid argument for `blocktrans`.

I am aware that I could solve this with javascript. I am looking for a more "Djangonic" solution.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to do this outside of template. Either with templatetag or in view. In any case... Instead of:

```
<a href="mailto:me@example.com?subject=_('Hello {{ username }}')|urlencode">Send email</a>
```

you need something like this:

```
import urllib
d = {'subject':ugettext(u"Hello %s" % username)}
```

and change the subject part for

```
value = urllib.urlencode(d)

'<a href="mailto:me@example.com?%s">Send email</a>' % value
```

If you are translating "hello" by the way, then you should probably consider translating "Send email" too :P

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the translation on the pinch brackets:

```
<a href="mailto:me@example.com?subject=_('Hello \{\{ username \}\}')|urlencode">Send email</a>
```

I hope this helps.